# Properties of rational function of two monotone functions

Tags: maxima-minima, rational-functions, monotone-functions

Consider two increasing functions $f,g:\mathbb{N}_{>0}\to \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and let $h:=f/g$ (we assume $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x>0$).
In other words, $f(x)< f(x+1)$, $g(x)< g(x+1)$ holds for all $x>0$ and $h(x)=f(x)/g(x)$.

We assume that $\lim_{x\to \infty}h(x)=0$.
Then, is $h$ unimodal (in $x>0$) ? i.e., $\cdots \leq h(x^*-1)\leq  h(x^*)\geq h(x^*+1) \geq\cdots$ for some $x^*>0$.
For example, $h(x)=x/(x^2+1)$ is unimodal (in $x>0$).

Comment: should it be $f,g:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ ?

Comment: Thanks, I will assume that $f,g:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $f(x)<f(y), g(x)<g(y)$ for all $x<y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.   Here is a counterexample:
$$ f(x)=e^{2x+\sin(x)}\quad g(x)=e^{2x-\sin(x)+\log(1+x^2)},$$
for $x>0$.
It is easy to check that both are monotone increasing, and that their ratio is not.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but $\lim_{x\to \infty}h(x)$ is not $0$ in that case?

Comment: I have changed things so that $h\to0$ at $\infty$.

Comment: Oh, it is true. Thank you for your nice counterexample.